# Receber mensagem da exception do Firebird no PHP

Tags: php, exceção, firebird, nginx

Meu script `PHP` não está recebendo a mensagem das `exceptions` que são geradas pelo `Firebird`. Tenho uma classe que realiza a conexão com o BD, executa o sql e desconecta.

Depurando o script, vi que a `exception` está sendo gerada, pois o script é interrompido, mas a mensagem não está sendo recebida pelo `PHP`. Para receber a `exception` estou utilizando `ibase_errmsg()`. A função da classe que é responsável pela execução do `sql` é esta:

```
function sql($host, $user, $pass, $query, $charset){
$this->connect($host, $user, $pass, $charset);
if ($this->conectou) {
    try {
        if ($this->result=ibase_query($query)){
            $this->disconnect($type);               
            return $this->result;
        } else {
            $errmsg = ibase_errmsg();
            //Debug
            echo $errmsg; //Nada esta mostrando aqui!!!
            $this->disconnect($type);
            throw new Exception($errmsg);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
  }
}
```

A princípio imaginei que o problema pudesse estar em `ibase_errmsg()`, mas, o mais intrigante é que rodando o mesmo script com Apache, a exception é mostrada normalmente.

> - Servidor: Debian
> - Firebird: 2.5 superclassic
> - Web Server: Nginx
> - PHP: 5.4.45
> - Processo do PHP: php-fpm

Comment: Troque `echo $errmsg;` por `var_dump($errmsg);` para testarmos.

Comment: troquei mas continua sem mensagem. Valeu pela dica!

Comment: Mas retorna algo? `NULL` ou `FALSE` ou `STRING ""`, seja mais claro por favor, se não tenho que perguntar as coisas picotada, complica demais assim ;)

Comment: Não retorna, na verdade passa direto pelo bloco da condição verdadeira, como se não tivesse ocorrido a `exception`.

Comment: Como eu suspeitava :D ... não tem nada haver com gerar o exception, o problema é no `ibase_query($query)`, me diga o que retorna se adicionar um var_dump assim `$this->result = ibase_query($query);
var_dump($this->result);
if ($this->result !== false) {`?

Comment: Retornou isto: `resource(8) of type (interbase result)`

Comment: Carlos isso significa que a query está correta, creio eu e assim não vai disparar a o `else`.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, por curiosidade descobri que a `exception` só está sendo gerada se eu fizer um `insert`, `update` ou `delete` na `procedure`. Fazendo `select` a mesma não gera a `exception`, deve ser por causa do `suspend` que é necessário ter. Como você citou na outra resposta, que o `Firebird` deve estar retornando `true` mesmo gerando a `exception`. Isso poderia ser uma falha do `Firebird`, será que existe um outro meio de contornar isso?

Comment: Vamos **[continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52125/discussion-between-guilherme-nascimento-and-carlos-andrade)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A partir da versão 5.0 do PHP a função `ibase_query` retorna o numero de linhas se for `INSERT`, `DELETE` e `UPDATE`, como explicado em https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.ibase-query.php#refsect1-function.ibase-query-returnvalues

Então é melhor usar uma identificação como `===` ou `!==` e para depurar melhor recomendo sempre usar `var_dump` ao invés de `echo` assim por exemplo:

```
$this->result = ibase_query($query);

if ($this->result !== false) {
    $this->disconnect($type);               
    return $this->result;
} else {
    $errmsg = ibase_errmsg();

    //Debug
    var_dump($errmsg); //Nada esta mostrando aqui!!!

    $this->disconnect($type);
    throw new Exception($errmsg);
}
```

Comment: Então, realmente você tem razão, mas mesmo alterando para esta condição é como se o banco de dados não tivesse gerando o erro. Eu peguei o mesmo `sql` que é passado para a função e executando diretamente no banco de dados, a `exception` é gerada normalmente. Não seria alguma configuração no `php` que possa estar desativada? tipo alguma configuração de aviso? Até para ter a certeza, alterei a `procedure` ao qual o `sql` faz o `select` colocando apenas a `exception` para ser gerada.

Comment: A `procedure` ficou da seguinte forma:
`CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE SP_TEST_EXCEPT (
    id_cliente integer)
returns (
    oresult smallint)
as
begin
  exception ERRO_003;
end`